# Removing a reaction on adding a reaction

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm wanting to remove a reaction when another reaction is adeed. For example if user had reacted to emoji 1 but reacts to emoji 2 then emoji 1 is removed or if the user had react to emoji 1 but reacts to emoji 4 instead then emoji 1 is removed.

I'm using a `async def on_raw_reaction_add():` event and defined the emojis I'd like to use however if I dide:

```
 await member.add_roles(role, reason='Added role')
        await message.remove_reaction(one, user)
        await message.remove_reaction(two, user)
        await message.remove_reaction(three, user)
```

This would remove all the emojis including the emoji the user selected.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
one = "1\N{COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP}"
two = "2\N{COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP}"
three = "3\N{COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP}"


@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    message_ids = [649600853048688642, ]
    channel = self.bot.get_channel(634023419482079232)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(649600853048688642)
    user = self.bot.get_user(payload.user_id)
    if not payload.guild_id:
        return 
    if payload.message_id not in message_ids: 
        return
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)  # You need the guild to get the member who reacted
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)  # Now you have the key part, the member who should receive the role
    restricted_role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Commands Revoked")
    role_name = emoji_role_map.get(payload.emoji.name)
    if restricted_role in member.roles:
        return
    if role_name:  # None if not found
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=role_name)
        await member.add_roles(role, reason='Added role')
        await message.remove_reaction(one, user)
        await message.remove_reaction(two, user)
        await message.remove_reaction(three, user)
```

Help appreciated.